# Possible to view postgres statistics by date?

Tags: postgresql, statistics, postgresql-9.3

I've been reviewing stats on indexes (e.g. pg_stat_user_indexes) to determine the effectiveness or lack thereof of our existing indexes. Over the past couple of months a lot of index work has gone on. Can I get stats on my indexes/tables since a certain date? Are is it always a collection of stats since the last pg_stat_reset()? So if I've got a table that is reporting a lot of table scans, but we actually introduced an index to handle to 3 months ago. The stats for those scans will still show up until I reset the stats right?

So would I need to reset my stats in order to get a an accurate depiction?

Is there any harm in reseting?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I get stats on my indexes/tables since a certain date?

No.

> Are is it always a collection of stats since the last `pg_stat_reset()`?

Yes.

> So would I need to reset my stats in order to get a an accurate depiction?

You need to do a stats reset to "forget" old data, yes.

There's no way to reset stats to "one week ago" or whatever, because no historical data is retained. They're just counters. It's possible to collect historical data by taking periodic copies of the stats counters and logging them to history tables, but the core PostgreSQL engine doesn't do this, as it tries to make sure that stats are as light-weight and low-cost as possible.

> Is there any harm in reseting?

None at all. The stats you're talking about are for performance tuning and analysis. They aren't used by the query planner.

It may be confusing that PostgreSQL has two kinds of stats:

- stats maintained by `ANALYZE` and autovacuum that're used to drive query planning decisions; and
- stats about index/table use that're maintained by the stats collector and are purely for admin use

You don't want to (and can't) reset the planner statistics. You can reset the index/table usage stats.

If you want to track historical trends, copy the stats data into a table that adds timestamps to let you track time-series data by calculating differences between counter values.

Comment: Is there a way to get the datetime the stats were last reset?

Comment: @tread Looks like `select pg_stat_get_db_stat_reset_time((select oid from pg_database where datname = current_database()));`